# Can't control logging levels when using jetty-runner

Tags: java, logging, maven-3, java.util.logging, jetty-9

I have a Java 8 Maven webapp project that I am running using `jetty-runner.jar`. Everything works fine, except I can't control the logging levels (INFO, WARNING, FINE, FINER etc.). Am using `java.util.logging` and OS is Win7.

I've tried the following:

- Created a `logging.properties` file in `src/main/resources` folder (ends up in `WEB-INF/classes` directory of the `war`).
- Renamed `logging.properties` to `jetty-logging.properties`
- Used `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties` (when the file was so named) with the command to run `jetty-runner`

  - `java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=WEB-INF/classes/logging.prop
    erties -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar target/xyz.war`
- Also tried `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties` (with a `/` in front of `WEB-INF`)

My logging file is simply:

```
.level  = WARNING
```

I haven't had to mess around with logging much before (except GAE projects), so not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are using a relative path so are you sure the working directory is what you expect?  Try using an absolute path to the logging.properties.

Comment: I am trying to use the properties file inside the war file, so can't use an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to load the `logging.properties` from [inside of the WAR file](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4801104) you have to use the [java.util.logging.config.class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).  Per the documentation:

> If the "java.util.logging.config.class" property is set, then the property value is treated as a class name. The given class will be loaded, an object will be instantiated, and that object's constructor is responsible for reading in the initial configuration. (That object may use other system properties to control its configuration.) The alternate configuration class can use readConfiguration(InputStream) to define properties in the LogManager.

Using that property you can use [Class.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) to locate the file inside of the WAR file.  Here is an example:

```
package foo.bar.baz;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;

public class JulConfig {

    /**
     * Install this as the -Djava.util.logging.config.class=foo.bar.baz.JulConfig
     * -Djava.util.logging.config.file=WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties
     * @throws Exception if there is a problem.
     */
    public JulConfig() throws Exception {
        String key = "java.util.logging.config.file";
        String file = System.getProperty(key, "logging.properties");
        final InputStream in = JulConfig.class.getResourceAsStream(file);
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(in);
                //System.clearProperty(key); //Optional.
            } finally {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(file);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason you have to do this is because the [LogManager uses java.io.File](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6344830) to locate the logging.properties.